# Using Pyral package with Komodo ide

Tags: python, rally, ca, pyral, komodo-ide

I'm using Python, write down in Komodo IDE, to create toolkit that works with CA agile central API service(Rally) - [Rally for Developer](https://help.rallydev.com/for-developers).
When using GET HTTP request, I encounter with several problems:

**1. Fetching partial records**  - if I set FETCH property == True not all records return. On the other hand, if I set FETCH with specific value/s from the query(e.g., FETCH = 'FormattedID'), the instance fetch all the records.
This is my GET request:

```
> rallyApiObjectModels = rally.get('HierarchicalRequirement',
> projectScopeDown = True, project="myProject", fetch=True,
> order="FormattedID", start=1, pagesize = 500);
```

And than:

```
 for _objModel in rallyApiObjectModels.data["Result"]
            print(_objModel)
```

**2. Low performance using Komodo ide** - when trying to fetch data from the HTTP request that is greater than 200, it takes for the end of time(e.g., pagesize =300 takes 11 min). On the other hand, using command promp is very fast for the same script when writing to file.
I set the same rally.get request like above and just print to IDE console:

```
print rallyApiObjectModels.data["Result"]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're running your code through the debugger then yes, it's going to be slow.  Nothing to be done about that.  If you're executing the file using Tools > Run Command or some other method that is not the debugger then we'd like to know about it to see if we can help.  Us devs answer questions in our forums all the time if you're interested http://community.komodoide.com/.  Sounds like you're good to go though dumping to a file :)

Comment: Tnx @cgchoffman ! I'll check it out !

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use fetch=true.  The performance is terrible, as you found.  It is much better to specify exactly the fields you want included in the response.  You should be able to use a page size of up to 2000, with the performance sweet spot being some balance between the set of fields fetched and your network latency.

I bet the Komodo IDE is just choking on the large response- unfortunately there's not much that can be done about that on the Rally end...

Comment: Tnx @Kyle Morse ! I tried specify all my fields but no success. Any suggestion for customize the Rally config file? About Komodo IDE - writing to file solve the problem !